# Run failed java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, gradle

I am uing gradle to build and to run a java project that ask user to enter words, and when "done" is typing, the program print a sorted string list.

When I build the project with the command gradle -build, it is successfully build, but when I try to run it, it looks like Gradle doesn't "let me time" to enter a word, and then Gradle tell me "no line found".

Here is an extract of my function void enter_words() in my java program :

```
    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    str=sc.nextLine();
```

Here is what Gradle told me when I use the gradle run command in the shell :

```
C:\Users\celine\Desktop\test2>gradle run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:runMain
Enter a word // the program is running but I can't enter a word
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
        at d.Project1.enter_words(Project1.java:42)
        at d.Project1.main(Project1.java:81)
:runMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runMain'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished wi
th non-zero exit value 1
```

---

Here is my java program :

```
package com.gumgum.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Project1 {

    private int max;
    private String[] userInputs;

    // constructors
    public Project1() {
        max=100;
        userInputs = new String[max];
    }

    public Project1(int n) {
        max=n;
        userInputs = new String[max];
    }

    //getter
    String[] getUserInputs() {
        return userInputs;
    }

    //setter: all words entered by the users are written in tab
    public void setUserInputs(String[] tab, int position, String str) {
        tab[position]=str;
    }

    //demande à l'utilisateur d'entrer un mot
    public void enter_words () {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int countWords=0;
        String str="";
        while ((countWords<3) || (str.equals("done")!=true)) {

            System.out.println("Enter a word");
            str=sc.nextLine();

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(str) == true)
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid word");
            else if (str.length()<=2) 
                System.out.println("Please enter at least 3 characters"); 

            if ((str.length()>=3) && (StringUtils.isBlank(str) != true)) {
                switch(str) {
                    case "done" :
                        if (countWords<3)
                            System.out.println("Please enter at least three words");
                        break;
                    default:
                        setUserInputs(this.userInputs,countWords,str);
                        countWords++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void lexico_order(String[] tab) {
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("");
        while(tab[i]!=null) {
            i++;
        }
        int k=0;
        Arrays.sort(tab, k, i);
        System.out.println("****** Sorted String List *******");
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
            System.out.println(tab[j]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project1 p;
        p = new Project1();
        p.enter_words();
        System.out.printf("ca marche");
        p.lexico_order(p.getUserInputs());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Adding:

```
run {
standardInput = System.in
}
```

to my build.gradle solved this problem for me

Comment: where should it put in? Like this? `android{run{}}`

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you!